# Controllers have to be invokable, How to change to a normal one - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, controller, laravel-10

I have multiple controllers with multiple functions. Despite that, Laravel expects a `__invoke()` method. Why is that so and how can I fix it?

Here's the error message:

```
     UnexpectedValueException 

  Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController].

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction.php:92
     88▕      */
     89▕     protected static function makeInvokable($action)
     90▕     {
     91▕         if (! method_exists($action, '__invoke')) {
  ➜  92▕             throw new UnexpectedValueException("Invalid route action: [{$action}].");
     93▕         }
     94▕
     95▕         return $action.'@__invoke';
     96▕     }

  i   `App\Http\Controllers\LoginController` is not invokable: The controller class `App\Http\Controllers\LoginController` is not invokable. Did you forget to add the `__invoke` method or is the controller's method missing in your routes file?

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction.php:47
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction::makeInvokable("App\Http\Controllers\LoginController")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:191
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction::parse("login", ["App\Http\Controllers\LoginController", "App\Http\Controllers\LoginController"])
```

##### web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', HomeController::class, 'home')->name('home');
Route::get('/login', LoginController::class, 'login')->name('login');
Route::get('/register', RegisterController::class, 'register')->name('register');
```

##### Controllers (all 3 are identical)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very important tha  you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#basic-controllers)... As Mikola stated, you did not put the class and the method (in that order) inside an array...

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, change the route definition syntax from:

```
Route::get('/', HomeController::class, 'home')->name('home');
Route::get('/login', LoginController::class, 'login')->name('login');
Route::get('/register', RegisterController::class, 'register')->name('register');
```

to

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
```

In the updated code, the controller and method are passed as an array instead of separate parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn´t see that on despite being such a stupid but simpel mistake.